# How can we check the total_supply of EVM?

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template

I have integrated pallet_evm in my blockchain? I want to check the total_supply of EVM, How could this be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a blockchain you can check the premined balance you have, see the frontier node template as example: https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/master/template/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L209

Where is creating a balance for three accounts:

- 0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558: 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,210,955 ETH
- 0x6be02d1d3665660d22ff9624b7be0551ee1ac91b:
  340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,210,955 ETH
- 0x1000000000000000000000000000000000000001:
  999,999,999,999,999,999,999,500 ETH

I am not sure if querying the pallet evm there is an easy way to get the total amount of tokens, but for example in Ethereum if you want to query the total supply of ETH is not that easy. You have to calculate it from the following events:

- The pre-mine amount.
- Proof-of-work mining rewards.
- Uncle Proof-of-work mining rewards.
- The EIP-1559 token burn.
- Proof-of-work rewards and penalties (Eth2).